# RSpec: Assert successful create request without assigns method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have this code in a `create` method inside a Rails controller:

```
if @product.save
  format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
```

To test this code, I have this expectation in an RSpec file:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns(:product))
```

Using `assigns` is deprecated/has been moved to a gem and frankly I don't care if `@product` or `@my_product` has been created in the controller. Actually I just want to know if I have been redirected to `/products/<some-id>`. Is there a (recommended) way to do so?

Comment: Which version of `rspec-rails` you are using?

Comment: I require `rspec-rails` without indicating any specific version and did `bundle update` today, so it's 4.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want render new you you'll need add `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to your **Gemfile**.

After read your comments i guess your action #create is look like that:

```
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

You could do a test like that:

```
  describe 'POST /products' do
    context 'when everithing is ok' do
      it 'returns the product' do
        post products_url, params: { product: { description: 'lorem ipsum', title: 'lorem ipsum' } }

        expect(response).to redirect_to(product_url(Product.last))
      end
    end

    context 'when something worong' do
      it 'redirect to new' do
        post products_url, params: { product: { description: 'lorem ipsum' } }

        expect(response).to render_template(:new)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, that (especially expecting `redirect_to(product_url(Product.last))`) did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

This [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950) explains why `assigns` is deprecated

> Testing what instance variables are set by your controller is a bad idea. That's grossly overstepping the boundaries of what the test should know about. You can test what cookies are set, what HTTP code is returned, how the view looks, or what mutations happened to the DB, but testing the innards of the controller is just not a good idea.

you can test the response status code using [have_http_status](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-http-status-matcher) matcher

```
expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the redirect has a 302 status code, while *success* is defined as 2xx status code. And there's another problem that's not in the code I posted: If invalid data is sent to the `create` method, the `products/new` view is rendered (with a 200 status code), so a POST request with valid data is classified as unsuccessful, while a request with invalid data is classified as successful. It needs to be the other way round.